# Caching Objects with Expensive Build & Allowing Updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am working on a caching manager for a MVC web application.  For this app, I have some very large objects that are costly to build.  During the application lifetime, I may need to create several of these objects, based upon user requests.  When built, the user will be working with the data in the objects, resulting in many read actions.  On occasion, I will need to update some minor data points in the cached object (create & replace would take too much time).

Below is a cache manager class that I have created to help me in this.  Beyond basic thread safety, my goals were to:

1. Allow multiple reads against a object, but lock all reads to that object upon an
   update request
2. Ensure that the object is only ever created 1 time if
   it does not already exist (keep in mind that its a long build
   action).
3. Allow the cache to store many objects, and maintain a lock
   per object (rather than one lock for all objects).

   ```
   public class CacheManager 
   {
       private static readonly ObjectCache Cache = MemoryCache.Default;
       private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim>
            Locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim>();
       private const int CacheLengthInHours = 1;

       public object AddOrGetExisting(string key, Func<object> factoryMethod)
       {
           Locks.GetOrAdd(key, new ReaderWriterLockSlim());

           var policy = new CacheItemPolicy 
             { 
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(CacheLengthInHours)
             };
           return Cache.AddOrGetExisting
               (key, new Lazy<object>(factoryMethod), policy);
       }

       public object Get(string key)
       {
           var targetLock = AcquireLockObject(key);
           if (targetLock != null)
           {
               targetLock.EnterReadLock();

               try
               {
                   var cacheItem = Cache.GetCacheItem(key);
                   if(cacheItem!= null)
                       return cacheItem.Value;
               }
               finally 
               {
                   targetLock.ExitReadLock();
               }
           }

           return null;
       }

       public void Update<T>(string key, Func<T, object> updateMethod)
       {
           var targetLock = AcquireLockObject(key);
           var targetItem = (Lazy<object>) Get(key);

           if (targetLock == null || key == null) return;
           targetLock.EnterWriteLock();

           try
           {
               updateMethod((T)targetItem.Value);
           }
           finally
           {
               targetLock.ExitWriteLock();
           }
       }

       private ReaderWriterLockSlim AcquireLockObject(string key)
       {
           return Locks.ContainsKey(key) ? Locks[key] : null;
       }
   }
   ```

Am I accomplishing my goals while remaining thread safe?  Do you all see a better way to achieve my goals?

Thanks!

UPDATE:  So the bottom line here was that I was really trying to do too much in 1 area.  For some reason, I was convinced that managing the Get / Update operations in the same class that managed the cache was a good idea.  After looking at Groo's solution & rethinking the issue, I was able to do a good amount of refactoring which removed this issue I was facing.

Comment: You are using both a `Cache`, and a `ConcurrentDictionary`? Why do you need the dictionary for? And you are only locking the access to the dictionary, not access to the object itself. Also, I don't see that you are locking when instantiating the object for the first time.

Comment: I think you may want to review the code base one more time as the dictionary plays the essential part to this locking strategy.  It keeps refernces to the locks that are synced with each cached item, thus allowing me to individually lock each item without impacting the other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think this class does what you need.

> Allow multiple reads against the object, but lock all reads upon an update request

You may lock all reads to the **cache manager**, but you are not locking reads (nor updates) to the actual cached instance.

> Ensure that the object is only ever created 1 time if it does not already exist (keep in mind that its a long build action).

<strike>I don't think you ensured that. You are not locking anything while adding the object to the dictionary (and, furthermore, you are adding a lazy constructor, so you don't even know when the object is going to be instantiated).</strike>

**Edit:** This part holds, the only thing I would change is to make `Get` return a `Lazy<object>`. While writing my program, I forgot to cast it and calling `ToString` on the return value returned `"Value not created".

> Allow the cache to store many objects, and maintain a lock per object (rather than one lock for all objects).

That's the same as point 1: you are locking the dictionary, not the access to the object. And your `update` delegate has a strange signature (it accepts a typed generic parameter, and returns an `object` which is never used). This means you are really modifying the object's properties, and these changes are immediately visible to any part of your program holding a reference to that object.

**How to resolve this**

If your object is mutable (and I presume it is), there is no way to ensure transactional consistency unless each of your properties also acquires a lock on each read access. A way to simplify this is to make it immutable (that why these are so popular for multithreading).

Alternatively, you may consider breaking this large object into smaller pieces and caching each piece separately, making them immutable if needed.

**[Edit] Added a race condition example:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CacheManager cache = new CacheManager();
        cache.AddOrGetExisting("item", () => new Test());

        // let one thread modify the item
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            cache.Update<Test>("item", i =>
            {
                i.First = "CHANGED";
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                i.Second = "CHANGED";

                return i;
            });
        });

        // let one thread just read the item and print it
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
        {
            var item = ((Lazy<object>)cache.Get("item")).Value;
            Log(item.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Log(item.ToString());
        });

        Console.Read();
    }

    class Test
    {
        private string _first = "Initial value";
        public string First
        {
            get { return _first; }
            set { _first = value; Log("First", value); }
        }

        private string _second = "Initial value";
        public string Second
        {
            get { return _second; }
            set { _second = value; Log("Second", value); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("--> PRINTING: First: [{0}], Second: [{1}]", First, Second);
        }
    }

    private static void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, message);
    }

    private static void Log(string property, string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: {1} property was changed to [{2}]", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, property, value);
    }
}
```

Something like this should happen:

```
t = 0ms  : thread A gets the item and prints the initial value
t = 250ms: thread B modifies the first property
t = 500ms: thread A prints the INCONSISTENT value (only the first prop. changed)
t = 750ms: thread B modifies the second property
```

Comment: I think you may want to review the code one more time.  Your assertions are not quite true (I think).  By using Lazy<T>, I am allowing the framework to handle my thread-safe construction.  As for locking reads, I am using a dictionary of lock objects to pair w/ my cache.  I never lock access to CacheManager or the dictionary.  The objects in the dictionary are locked. By matching keys between the cache & dictionary, I can handle locks on each cached item.

Comment: Yes, you are right about adding, I didn't think it through. When two threads call `AddOrGetExisting` at the same time, you get a unique lock object in your `Locks` collection, and the cache will only get a single `Lazy` instance. The main problem is that you are updating **properties** of the object (inside the `Update` method), and there is nothing which ensures that another thread doesn't already have a reference to your object. *I never lock access to CacheManager or the dictionary. The objects in the dictionary are locked.* - then what are you doing inside the `Get` method?

Comment: @Nathan: it's possible that we didn't understand each other, so I've added an example app which shows what I'm talking about. My only concern is that locking inside the `Update` method gives no guarantee that the object's state is consistent in other parts of your program. Also, as a minor detail, I would change `Get` method's signature to return `Lazy<object>`, because that's what it always returns regardless of the actual type. On the other hand, if your instances were immutable, and you swapped the instance in the dictionary on update, then I would consider it to be fully thread safe.

Comment: @Nathan: so, the bottom line is: the idea of locking inside `Update` and using a delegate to ensure everyone gets the latest instance is good if two threads are competing to update an object, but you don't get any benefit from locking inside the `Get` method. You may get inconsistent reads in any other thread which has a reference (and of course, nothing stops you from changing the object outside the `Update` method, but let's presume that you are careful to avoid that).

Comment: Marking this answer as the solution as it really is what guided me to refactoring the underlying class.  Thanks!